# Using swipe tabs with drawerlayout

Tags: android, tabs, swipe, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have been trying to do this for a couple of days and can't figure it out.

I have a basic navigation drawer, taken and adapted from the sample app, and now I want swipable tabs when the user selects the first item in the drawer, instead of a relative layout it has normally.

I only want this in the first item, the others may keep their usual relative layout.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?